# Using FileWriter and keeping LineBreaks/WhiteSpace

Tags: java, oop

Hello I'm currently using the Java `FileWriter` system with a `HashTable` to recreate a decoded message. I'm attempting to recreate a decoded message by looping through a file that contains all the encoded key value pairs (10111 = C) and writing to a text file

My Encoded KV Pairs
https://github.com/DijonLee/Project2/blob/master/freq.txt

```
prop.load(new FileReader(freqFile));
for (Map.Entry entry : prop.entrySet()) {
    // map.put((String) entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
}
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(freqFile));

String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // System.out.println(line); // ensure my line breaks are okay

    if (line.contains("=")) {
        String[] strings = line.split("=");
        map.put(strings[0], (strings[1]));
    }
}
```

Here is where I attempt to "Decode" my text based on the KV Pairs

```
FileReader inputStream = null;
inputStream = new FileReader("encoded.txt");

FileWriter outputStream = null;
outputStream = new FileWriter("ur_dec.txt");

int c;
String decoder = "";
String key = "";

while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {  // loop through file
    char cToChar = (char) c;              // get char
    decoder += cToChar;                  // build string
    if (map.containsValue(decoder)) {
        for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (decoder.equals(entry.getValue())) {
                key = (String) entry.getKey();
                decoder = "";
                outputStream.write(key); // 
            }
            break; // breaking because its one to one map 
        }
    }
}
```

Although my program works it appears to strip tabs and other white spaces that I'd like to keep while I encode and decode it and I'm not too sure why

Comment: You could replace for loop over map with `map.getKey(value)`. But better to switch keys and values: map.containsValue(value) and map.getKey(value) each has time complexity O(n); map.contains(key) and map.get(key) each has complexity O(1).

Comment: I notice there are initial two lines in the file's text which seem to have _empty string_ and a _space_ as keys. You can observe them using this code and take necessary action: `map.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().equals("00") || e.getValue().equals("01010")).forEach(e -> System.out.println("Value and its key: " + "[" + e.getValue() + "]" +"[" + e.getKey() + "]"));`

Comment: You are not showing how are you encrypting the document. You dictionary (freq.txt) missing tab, new line symbols, etc. Because of it key = "" (empty string) when it processing tab, new line, etc.

Comment: Consider using [`java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

Comment: I am encrypting my document using a Huffman Encoding Algorithm. Full code can be seen here https://github.com/DijonLee/DataStructures/blob/master/Java/Project2/HuffmanSubmit.java